# I'm having trouble getting my code to create a file

Tags: xcode, c++11

I'm working on this assignment but I can't get my code to show a file. Also, in her video, she has something called a compiled executable program where it writes the files, but I don't know how to add my own.
[Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ggeE.png)
[My professor's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epHbX.png)

I've been trying to find a clear answer but haven't had any luck. I've tried running the code by itself and tried making my own text file in the file location.

Comment: Have you complied/linked your  code to generate an executable program ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do not add `\n` to the file name, it doesn't make any sense there. `outputFile.open("file.txt");`, not `outputFile.open("file.txt\n");`